# Error flash.ocx when make setup installer in ms. visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I want to create a setup installer on a project that I created . but I got a problem when creating the output file , error appears :

> The following files may have dependencies that can not be determinited automatically . please confirm that all dependencies have been added to the project . C : \ windows \ system32 \ macromed \ flash \ flash.ocx

I had to update the adobe flash and debug platform change to x86 , but nothing changes. please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

That means you have to install related software to your project on the client pc after installing your project. for eg: if you are using Crystal Report you have to install crystalReportRuntime (depending on which version you have used while building project).